# cannot find symbol - ArrayList; cannot find symbol - Integer

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

I have imported both ArrayList and Integer. In my code I use the symbols in multiple places but I only get an error on one line.

Here are the import statements:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.lang.Integer;
```

Here are the pieces of code that compile properly:

```
ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
primes.add(2);
primes.add(3);
primes.add(5);
primes.add(7);

private static void addPrime(ArrayList<Integer> primes)
{
    int newNumber;
    int x;
}
```

This piece of code return the symbol errors listed above:

```
while (lastValue < half)
{
    addPrime(ArrayList<Integer> primes);
    lastValue = primes.get(primes.size()-1);
}
```

I have done research on the problem but the only answer I can find is that the symbols were not imported properly at the beginning of the program.

Comment: What do you think `addPrime(ArrayList<Integer> primes);` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: (The syntax on that statement is invalid, and your intention is not clear)

Comment: Try changing addPrime(ArrayList<Integer> primes); to addPrime(primes);  You don't need to specify the type when calling a method.  You may have other issues though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little background if you are not aware of already:

```java
private static void addPrime(ArrayList<Integer> primes)
{
    int newNumber;
    int x;
}
```

is the `method` definition, where we define what the method will do for us. To make it do something for us we call the method passing the arguments, eg. `addPrime(argument)`. Here you got to pass actual `argument` variable of `type` which you have defined in `method` definition.

So `addPrime(primes)` will work for you.

Comment: I was not aware that the type of argument did not need to be passed when calling the method. This worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the value type when calling a function. So instead of `addPrime(ArrayList<Integer> primes);` just simply do `addPrime(primes);`

Answer (score 0):

The addPrime(...) function you have does not do anything in the example you gave.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Integer;

public class test
{
  private static ArrayList<Integer> addPrime(ArrayList<Integer> primes, int num)
  {
    //Seems like you are trying to add primes to the list?
    primes.add(num);
    return primes;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    primes.add(2);
    primes.add(3);
    primes.add(5);
    primes.add(7);

    //Usage looks like
    primes = addPrime(primes, 13);

    // This will return 13 as the number 13 is the 5th element
    System.out.println(primes.get(4));
  }
}
```

Coded a bit better would be creating an object class so you do not keep passing around an array list

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Integer;


public class IntArrList
{
  private ArrayList<Integer> primes;

  public IntArrList() {
    primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }

  public void addPrime(int num)
  {
    primes.add(num);
  }

  public int getPrimeListValue(int index)
  {
    return primes.get(index);
  }

  public ArrayList<Integer> getPrimeList()
  {
    return primes;
  }
}

public class test
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    IntArrList arrL = new IntArrList();

    arrL.addPrime(2);
    arrL.addPrime(3);
    arrL.addPrime(5);
    arrL.addPrime(7);

    // This will return 7 as the number 7 is the 4th element
    System.out.println(arrL.getPrimeListValue(3));
  }
}
```